# Can't send attach files with SwiftMailer and Symfony3

Tags: php, swiftmailer, symfony

Hollo,
I try to send mail with **symfony3** using **SwiftMailer**. Everything work like a charm when i don't include attach file. 
When i try to attach file, email isn't sent and no error is generated.
I don't know if it's due to an error in file path but the file is correctly located in /doc/temp directory in Symfony **web** directory.

My source code is bellow:

```
            $message =  \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject("Subject")
                ->setFrom("from@gmail.com")
                ->setTo("to@gmail.com")
            ;

            $message->setBody($this->renderView(
                'xxxx.email.twig'
            ), "text/html");

            $message->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath('/doc/temp/file.pdf'));

            $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

Thanks for your help and sorry if i have some mistakes, english isn't my main language.

Comment: Did you put the code in try/catch blocks to see if it could catch any errors?

Comment: No i didn't, but i find the issue. it's due to file path.

Answer (score 1):

I solve my issue. it's due to file path. file path must be absolute. bellow is the correct code:

```
        $message =  \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject("Subject")
            ->setFrom("from@gmail.com")
            ->setTo("to@gmail.com")
        ;

        $message->setBody($this->renderView(
            'xxxx.email.twig'
        ), "text/html");

        $message->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath($this->get('kernel')->getRootDir()."/../web/doc/temp/file.pdf"));

        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```